# php function not working correctly after the first 7 runs

Tags: php, function, class, odbc

hi i have a function that gets Data from an ODBC connection

```
public function SageData() {
    $this->Arr = array();
    $conn = odbc_connect('Data hub', '', '');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE], [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[cycletime]
    FROM [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN]
     WHERE ((([SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE])='$this->name'));

";

    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }

    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {

        $this->Cycletime = odbc_result($rs, "cycletime");
    }

    odbc_close($conn);
    return round($this->Cycletime, 2);
}
```

This function is part of a class below is the code to create a new object in the class, In the function the $this->name corresponds to the ZW01001 and so on numbers

```
Machinecycle("ZW01001", "ZW01001Percent", 0);
Machinecycle("ZW01004", "ZW01004Percent", 1);
Machinecycle("ZW01005", "ZW01005Percent", 2);
```

the function is called by another function in the class to turn the data in to a percentage i can use see below

```
public function GetM() {

    $q = $this->Cycle();
    $qq = $this->SageData();

    $this->M = $q - $qq;
  //  $this->P = $this->M / $this->sageData();

    if ($qq == 0) {
        $this->P = 0;
    } else {
        $this->P = $this->M / $this->sageData();
    }

    return round($this->P, 2);
}
```

The Values outputted by GetM are put in to an array, my problem is that when i run this i get the data for the first 7 out of 14 objects and this error for the rest of them

```
Notice: Undefined property: machine::$Cycletime in C:\Somepath\Datatest.php on line 104
```

Line 104 is this part

```
    return round($this->Cycletime, 2);
```

What i do not understand is why it is doing this after the first 7 and failing on the rest the data is there

Comment: Have you taken a look at `'$this->name'`. It appears to be valid sql but you are actually looking for '$this->name'. Echo out `$sql` inside `SageData()` to make sure it's what you expected.

Comment: Echoing the Sql seems to give the expected result i built the query inside access first and it worked there, also if there was an issue with the query it would't get any data? it's getting the first 7 rows

Answer (score 0):

Well let's first state the obvious, in this bit

```
return round($this->Cycletime, 2);
```

$this->Cycletime seems to be undefined at the point where it spams the errors.

Next i see that this Cycletime is received from your odbc connection.

```
$this->Cycletime = odbc_result($rs, "cycletime");
```

Have you in fact checked that it is set all the time? because it looks like the query simply isn't returning data. So in order to fix it, make sure that your query does what it is supposed to and delivers the Cycletime.

Comment: The query returns Nulls in PHP after the 7th row, the query was built in ms access using the data im trying to get and it works fine there, if there was an issues with the sql then it would not get any data?

Comment: Could you post a var_dump of the $rs in the while loop? just put it in a pastebin post or something. So: 
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    var_dump($rs);